# Meteor publication: Hiding certain fields in an array document field?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
    _id: af3F3afafaa,
    firstName: "John",
    family: [{name: "David", relation: "brother", alive: true},
             {name: "Susan", relation: "mother", alive: false}]
}
```

Is there a way to write a publication that hides a field in the family field array? So if I subscribed to the publication I would get:

```
    {
    _id: af3F3afafaa,
    firstName: "John",
    family: [{name: "David", alive: true},
             {name: "Susan", alive: false"}]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers), something like this could work:

```
Meteor.publish('family', function(famId) {
  return Families.find(famId, {
    fields : {
      "family.relation" : 0 //Exclude family.relation from the sent data
    }
  });
});
```