# Publish all fields in document but just part of an array in the document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo collection in which the documents have a field that is an array. I want to be able to publish everything in the documents except for the elements in the array that were created more than a day ago. I suspect the answer will be somewhat similar to this question.

[Meteor publication: Hiding certain fields in an array document field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793161/meteor-publication-hiding-certain-fields-in-an-array-document-field)

Instead of limiting fields in the array, I just want to limit the elements in the array being published.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

EDIT

Here is an example document:

```
{
   _id: 123456,
   name: "Unit 1",
   createdAt: (datetime object),
   settings: *some stuff*,
   packets: [
     {
        _id: 32412312,
        temperature: 70,
        createdAt: *datetime object from today*
     },
     {
        _id: 32412312,
        temperature: 70,
        createdAt: *datetime from yesterday*
      }
    ]
 }
```

I want to get everything in this document except for the part of the array that was created more than 24 hours ago. I know I can accomplish this by moving the packets into their own collection and tying them together with keys as in a relational database but if what I am asking were possible, this would be simpler with less code.

Comment: you can add an example json document and that would help add more information

Comment: @anish I added an example for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in your publish method:

```
Meteor.publish("pubName", function() {
  var collection = Collection.find().fetch(); //change this to return your data
  _.each(collection, function(collectionItem) {
    _.each(collectionItem.packets, function(packet, index) {
      var deadline = Date.now() - 86400000 //should equal 24 hrs ago
      if (packet.createdAt < deadline) {
        collectionItem.packets.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Though you might be better off storing the last 24 hours worth of packets as a separate array in your document. Would probably be less taxing on the server, not sure.

Also, code above is untested. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! That worked but I ended up deciding to move them over to their own collection to make the publish method less taxing on the server.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the $elemMatch projection 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

So in your case, it would be

```js
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(today);
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1); 

collection.find({}, //find anything or specifc
{
  fields: {
    'packets': {
      $elemMatch: {$gt : {'createdAt' :  yesterday /* or some new Date() */}}
    }
  }
});
```

However, $elemMatch only returns the ***FIRST*** element matching your condition. To return more than 1 element, you need to use the [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/) framework, which will be more efficient than _.each or forEach, particularly if you have a large array to loop through.

```js
collection.rawCollection().aggregate([
{
    $match: {} 
},
{
    $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if : {$or: [{$gt: ["$createdAt",yesterday]},"$packets"]},
            then: "$$DESCEND",
            else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
}], function (error, result ){

});
```

You specify the $match in a way similar to find({}). Then all the documents that match your conditions get pipped into the $redact which is specified by the $cond.

$redact scans the document from top level to bottom. At the top level, you have _id, name, createdAt, settings, packets; hence {$or: [***,"$packets"]}

The presence of $packets in the $or allows the $redact to scan the second level which contain the _id, temperature and createdAt; hence {$gt: ["$createdAt",yesterday]}

This is async, you can use Meteor.wrapAsync to wrap around the function.

Hope this help

Comment: Are you bypassing the meteor API by calling `coll.rawCollection()`? If you are, perhaps a new would help out some people. Also, would this publication still be reactive? Because I note that `meteorhacks:aggregate` is not reactive.